# WebStorm highlights React component when props passed through react-redux connect function

Tags: reactjs, redux, webstorm, react-redux

I have a container component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
     someEntities: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
  ....
}

export default connect(state => ({ someEntities: state.someEntities })(MyComponent)
```

So I am passing props via `connect` to this component, but when I place component in code, like:

```
....
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
....
<div><MyComponent /></div>
....
```

WebStorm highlights `MyComponent` and gives me an error: `Element MyComponent doesn't have required attribute someEntities`.

I am using version 2016.3.1. Is this an error? Should I use `propTypes` in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue, tracked as [WEB-21692](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21692); please follow it for updates (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135-How-to-follow-YouTrack-issues-and-receive-notifications)